# How do I reparent an entire model (and accompanying objects) to another armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I have a model composed of several objects: the main one is a body parented to the armature using vertex groups; there is head parented directly to the head bone, and there are also supporting objects for attaching other props, also parented directly to bones - the model wasn't originally made in blender and that's how it's imported. Props attached to the support objects are parented to them using constaraints.

Now, I obtained a modified skeleton that has added IK for arms and legs. Apart from this one thing, the names of deform bones, their locations etc. are all the same. Is there a quick way (or a script) to reparent everything - main body, head and the support objects - to the new skeleton without the offsets blowing up? If it was just one character, I would do it slowly by hand, but there are lots of them - all with the same structure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed sound scriptable. Here's some docks.

Python API on parenting: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=parent#bpy.types.Object.parent

Parenting Inverse explained: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html?highlight=inverse%20parenting

The process sounds simple enough, though I don't know for sure without seeing the direct file.